# Does adding a Transient Property to a Core Data Entity require a new version model?

Tags: core-data, core-data-migration, iphonecoredatarecipes

I have an existing data model with already existing entities. I would like to add a new property to an entity without changing the the core data model version. Can this be done by a Transient Property, since Transient Properties are never actually saved to the DB table?

Can't find any documentation on this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After some researching this and many personal trials, it seems like adding a Transient Property does **not** require you to create a new version of the model